# Feedback on first programming project, browser compatibility

Tags: php, javascript, raphael, feedback

I know this isn't a straightforward question but I would really appreciate some feedback on this. This has been my first shot at programming and when I started it, I got some really good help from here.

http://koti.mbnet.fi/bugs/pohjoisespoo/ <- You'll find the site there
http://koti.mbnet.fi/bugs/pohjoisespoo/kartta3.js <- All the javascript
http://koti.mbnet.fi/bugs/pohjoisespoo/raphael-zpd.js <- The zoom pan drag script (by somnidea) 
http://koti.mbnet.fi/bugs/pohjoisespoo/sivu.css

Most of my issues are probably caused by my poor programming but also I think the zoom and panning script I'm using (https://github.com/somnidea/raphael-zpd) doesn't work with IE. I'm ready to change the whole script if it's the best option so be honest. However, I don't need IE6 support and I'm fine with even IE7 support missing. However, I believe there's some issues with it on Firefox v.3 as well. Newer Firefoxes and Google Chrome should work.

My next phase is to create a simple collapsible comment section under each of the bubble info sections. I'm guessing PHP is the way to go. What I need is super simple messaging board where conversations can be continued under comments to the main tree which can be collapsed. There's some tutorials for similar things online but if anyone knows a good method I'd appreciate the guidance. As you can guess I have no experience with databases etc. so I don't know if security could be an issue with my beginner skills. I also need a simple moderation tool. Otherwise what i'd like to do is let the users attach pins to the map which would show when a comment is highlighted. Is this kind of interaction between the PHP and JS feasible?

I appreciate any tips with anything.

Thank you for your help,
Ilkka Syrjakari

Comment: I think you should first find a good PHP/MySQL tutorial and follow it through so that you understand basic PHP and basic database create-read-update-delete(CRUD) applications.

Comment: Just a quick notice: *TEXT* in SVG is a STUPID design idea.  Text browsers give a BLANK page.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: Right, I thought it wasn't the best option but I had some problems with it: I couldn't get the buttons on the map to link properly. I tried linking simply to a location but that wasn't convenient as it automatically scrolled the browser down to the #. How could I link it properly? I do like the fade in animation with the text as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the numerous tutorials combining PHP with jQuery - which can do all your back-end AJAX calls, and front end magic (dialogs, show/hide content etc).

jQuery is ideal for interaction with Google Maps.

And knocking up the rest with php/std html/bits of jQuery should be fairly simple once you have got yourself a bit of basic understanding.

By all means, come and post specific questions as needed! :)

**EDIT**

You will also want to look up php's GD (php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) functionality :) Using GD you can load an image then add stuff to it.

Comment: By all means, come back and ask specifics when you have done some initial experimentation with this combination.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look in to trying to replicate this with jQuery. However, I don't think Google Maps is my answer as all I really need is simply few layers on top of a raster map. I think Google Maps over complicates things, I don't need actual real life coordinates for the map, but instead I just need coordinates on the vector image.